# Implement cursor when select value changes name

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I cannot seem to successfully implement the cursor what I change the statement name picked from `select`,

For example:

```
SELECT userid as user_no, CURSOR(SELECT user_no
   FROM my_table.punter P
   WHERE P.user_no = Q.user_no)
   FROM another_table.maria_punter Q;
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00904: "Q"."USER_NO": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the column alias given in the same `SELECT` clause; instead, use the unaliased column name from the table:

```sql
SELECT userid as user_no,
       CURSOR(
         SELECT user_no
         FROM   my_table.punter P
         WHERE P.user_no = Q.userid
       )
FROM   another_table.maria_punter Q;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EfZKaePg)